# Best way to format integer as string with leading zeros?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I need to add leading zeros to integer to make a string with defined quantity of digits ($cnt).
What the best way to translate this simple function from PHP to Python:

```
function add_nulls($int, $cnt=2) {
    $int = intval($int);
    for($i=0; $i<($cnt-strlen($int)); $i++)
        $nulls .= '0';
    return $nulls.$int;
}
```

Is there a function that can do this?

Comment: your code is producing notice, btw

Comment: http://php.net/printf is the way to go in php

Comment: @SilentGhost, or str_pad

Comment: Why use $ before variables?

Answer (score 846, accepted):

You can use the `zfill()` method to pad a string with zeros:

```
In [3]: str(1).zfill(2)
Out[3]: '01'
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the same only return an actual integer like 004 not a string like '004'?

Comment: @Ajay 004 isn't an actual integer

Comment: Why is 004 not an integer? Python says `004 == 4` is true, and as far as I know mathematics agrees.

Comment: The way `004` is parsed by the compiler, and then represented in memory, is exactly the same as `4`. The only time a difference is visible is in the `.py` source code. If you need to store information like "format this number with leading zeros until the hundreds place", integers alone cannot provide that - you need to use alternate data structures (string work well in this case)

Comment: Need to say that this is not correct. The fact that `004 == 4` is kinda fortune. The way interpreter (python is not compiled) parses ints is different for ints starting with a leading `0`. If a number starts with `0` then it is considered as 8-nary number. So yeah, `004 == 4`, but `040 != 40` because `040 = 4 * 8 + 0 = 32`.

Comment: To clarify a couple of things: 1. That is true only for parsing of integer literals, not for conversion of strings to ints - eg. if you do a = 010 then the value of a will be 8 but if you do a = int("010") the value of a will be 10. 2. Only Python 2 behaves this way - in python 3, a = 010 would give a syntax error. Octals in python 3 start with 0o, eg. 0o10 (presumably to avoid this exact confusion).

Comment: Thank you!   I used this to display time via an f'string without pulling in a time library
i.e  instead of displaying  12:7  I was able to display 12:07 with the following code

final_min = str(final_min).zfill(2)
new_time = f'{final_hr}:{final_min}'

Answer (score 265):

The standard way is to use format string modifiers. These format string methods are available in most programming languages (via the sprintf function in c for example) and are a handy tool to know about.

To output a string of length 5:

---

**... in Python 3.5 and above: f-strings.**

```
i = random.randint(0, 99999)
print(f'{i:05d}')
```

Search for f-strings [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) for more details.

---

... Python 2.6 and above:

```
print '{0:05d}'.format(i)
```

... before Python 2.6:

```
print "%05d" % i
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Comment: So what if you don't know the number of zeros before runtime? Let's say the length of a list?

Comment: @Zelphir you can dynamically create the formatting string, `[('{{0:0{0:d}d}}').format(len(my_list)).format(k) for k in my_list]`

Comment: I've chosen to concat the format string instead, inserting the length of a list for example. Are there any advantages of your way of doing it?

Comment: There is no need to use `str.format()` when all the template contains is one `{...}` placeholder. Avoid parsing the template and use the `format()` function instead: `format(i, '05d')`

Comment: @Mark There is no need to use nested/stacked formats. The number of digits can be variable: `[('{0:0{1}d}').format(k, len(my_list)) for k in my_list]` --- with f-string: `[f'{k:0{len(my_list)}d}' for k in my_list]` --- It is weird that the number of digits is determined by the number of items. You probably want to prepare `max_digits` and use `[f'{k:0{max_digits}d}' for k in my_list]`

Answer (score 127):

Python 3.6 f-strings allows us to add leading zeros easily:

```
number = 5
print(f' now we have leading zeros in {number:02d}')
```

Have a look at [this good post](https://cito.github.io/blog/f-strings/) about this feature.

Comment: This is the most pythonic, and certainly my favourite of the answers so far.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer

Answer (score 80):

You most likely just need to format your integer:

```
'%0*d' % (fill, your_int)
```

For example,

```
>>> '%0*d' % (3, 4)
'004'
```

Comment: The question is - how to add not permanent quantity of zeros

Comment: This is not permanent - in fact you cannot add zeroes permanently to the from of an int - that would then be interpreted as an octal value.

Comment: @Matthew Schnickel: I think the OP wants to know a method to compute the number of zeros he needs. Formatting handles that fine. And int(x, 10) handles the leading zeros.

Answer (score 24):

Python 2.6 allows this:

```
add_nulls = lambda number, zero_count : "{0:0{1}d}".format(number, zero_count)

>>>add_nulls(2,3)
'002'
```

Answer (score 21):

For Python 3 and beyond:
str.zfill() is still the most readable option

But it is a good idea to look into the new and powerful str.format(), what if you want to pad something that is not 0?

```
    # if we want to pad 22 with zeros in front, to be 5 digits in length:
    str_output = '{:0>5}'.format(22)
    print(str_output)
    # >>> 00022
    # {:0>5} meaning: ":0" means: pad with 0, ">" means move 22 to right most, "5" means the total length is 5

    # another example for comparision
    str_output = '{:#<4}'.format(11)
    print(str_output)
    # >>> 11##

    # to put it in a less hard-coded format:
    int_inputArg = 22
    int_desiredLength = 5
    str_output = '{str_0:0>{str_1}}'.format(str_0=int_inputArg, str_1=int_desiredLength)
    print(str_output)
    # >>> 00022
```

Answer (score 8):

You have at least two options:

- str.zfill: `lambda n, cnt=2: str(n).zfill(cnt)`
- `%` formatting: `lambda n, cnt=2: "%0*d" % (cnt, n)`

If on Python >2.5, see a third option in clorz's answer.

Answer (score 4):

#### One-liner alternative to the built-in `zfill`.

This function takes `x` and converts it to a string, and adds zeros in the beginning only and only if the length is too short:

```
def zfill_alternative(x,len=4): return ( (('0'*len)+str(x))[-l:] if len(str(x))<len else str(x) )
```

To sum it up - build-in: `zfill` is good enough, but if someone is curious on how to implement this by hand, here is one more example.

Answer (score 1):

A straightforward conversion would be (again with a function):

```
def add_nulls2(int, cnt):
    nulls = str(int)
    for i in range(cnt - len(str(int))):
        nulls = '0' + nulls
    return nulls
```

Answer (score -3):

This is my Python function:

```
def add_nulls(num, cnt=2):
  cnt = cnt - len(str(num))
  nulls = '0' * cnt
  return '%s%s' % (nulls, num)
```

Comment: Which is what str.zfill does :)

Comment: yes :) another method is this:
'%03d' % 8