# In Python, how to specify a format when converting int to string?

Tags: python, string

In Python, how do I specify a format when converting int to string?

More precisely, I want my format to add leading zeros to have a string 
with constant length. For example, if the constant length is set to 4:

- 1 would be converted into "0001"
- 12 would be converted into "0012"
- 165 would be converted into "0165"

I have no constraint on the behaviour when the integer is greater than what can allow the given length (9999 in my example).

How can I do that in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Best way to format integer as string with leading zeros?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/733454/64633)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`"%04d"` where the 4 is the constant length will do what you described.

You can read about string formatting [here.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html)

Update for Python 3:

`{:04d}` is the equivalent for strings using the `str.format` method or `format` builtin function. See the [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/string.html#formatspec) documentation.

Answer (score 22):

You could use the `zfill` function of `str` class. Like so -

```
>>> str(165).zfill(4)
'0165'
```

One could also do `%04d` etc. like the others have suggested. But I thought this is more pythonic way of doing this...

Answer (score 8):

With **`python3`** format and the **new 3.6** *formatted string literals* **`f""`**:

```
>>> i = 5
>>> "{:4n}".format(i)
'   5'
>>> "{:04n}".format(i)
'0005'
>>> f"{i:4n}"
'   5'
>>> f"{i:04n}" 
'0005'
```

Answer (score 5):

Try [formatted string printing](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/typesseq-strings.html):

`print "%04d" % 1` Outputs 0001

Answer (score 4):

Use the percentage (`%`) operator:

```
>>> number = 1
>>> print("%04d") % number
0001
>>> number = 342
>>> print("%04d") % number
0342
```

Documentation is [over here](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

The advantage in using `%` instead of zfill() is that you parse values into a string in a more legible way:

```
>>> number = 99
>>> print("My number is %04d to which I can add 1 and get %04d") % (number, number+1)
My number is 0099 to which I can add 1 and get 0100
```