# In python, how to convert sting to int, (those string might begin with 0)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this question the reverse problem as
[In Python, how to specify a format when converting int to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3813735/in-python-how-to-specify-a-format-when-converting-int-to-string/3813811)

here I have string "0001" to integer 1

string "0023" to integer 23

I wish to use this on pandas dataframe since I have column looks like:

```
dic = {'UPCCode': ["00783927275569", "0007839272755834", "003485934573", "06372792193", "8094578237"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dic)
```

I wish it become some thing like this

```
dic = {'UPCCode': [783927275569, 7839272755834, 3485934573, 6372792193, 8094578237]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dic)
```

if I use int(001) or float(0023)
it will gives me this error

SyntaxError: leading zeros in decimal integer literals are not permitted; use an 0o prefix for octal integers

Comment: try `df['UPCCode'] = df['UPCCode'].astype(int)`

Comment: int("00783927275569") is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `pd.to_numeric`:

```
df['UPCCode'] = pd.to_numeric(df['UPCCode'])
print(df)

         UPCCode
0   783927275569
1  7839272755834
2     3485934573
3     6372792193
4     8094578237
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, just use the `astype` method:

```
>>> df = df.astype(int)
>>> df
         UPCCode
0   783927275569
1  7839272755834
2     3485934573
3     6372792193
4     8094578237
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply this for column 'UPCCode' alone, do like this:

```
df = df['UPCCode'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello I found some way to do that just try:

```
df["UPCCode"] = df["UPCCode"].str.strip("0")
df["UPCCode"] = df["UPCCode"].astype(int)
```

Comment: `strip("0")` will remove trailing zeroes as well, this is not desirable.