# ImageMagick - maximal number of frames?

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I am using ImageMagick to convert sequence of `png` files to an animated `gif`. Basically the command is

```
convert -delay 5 img/gif_part_*.png animation.gif
```

The files go from `gif_part_1.png` to `gif_part_27.png`, but the gif starts at `gif_part_10.png`(maybe 9) and goes to the last. You can see it here. Stack won't allow me to upload the `gif` file, so I'll edit it later.

So is there a restriction on the number of files I can make into a `gif` (now it looks like the maximum is about 18)? I am working on turtle graphics and I want to show the process when the graphics is created by recursive function. The number of `png` files might be hundred or more.

I have also tried using ffmpeg but could not make it working.

**Update**

I have tried making a `gif` out of two smaller `gif`s, and it done the job. But it is horrible way I think - that would be so much of a work, putting it all together.

I think the problem might be in naming the files. I have read somewhere, that adding zero might be necessary, since `gif_part_10.png` might come before `gif_part_1.png`.

Comment: You are correct, when I had a project like this I numbered my frames from `frame_000.png` to `frame_108.png` and it worked perfectly from there.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Yes, it is working now! Great, but now I am not sure whether I should delete it, or edit the Q or answer it..:)

Comment: It looks like you came back and edited about a half hour after you posted. In a case like this, I figure it'd be okay if you answered your own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the solution is in my updated question. But for better readability I will add an answer. The problem was in naming individual `png` files. When ImageMagick-command `convert` creates a `gif` file it needs to sort the `png` files somehow. The **wrong** naming would be

```
img1.png
img2.png
.
img10.png
.
.
img90.png
```

Because `convert` would in this case put `img10.png` before `img1.png`, which most certainly ruins the output. The **correct** way is this:

```
img01.png
img02.png
img03.png
img04.png
img05.png
img06.png
img07.png
img08.png
img09.png
img10.png
.
.
.
img90.png
```

Now `convert` will sort the files in correct order

---

Since I have been creating the `png` files on my own I could easily correct the script, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/733478/2377489) neat approach. I assume you know, how much pictures you want to convert into a `gif`, lets put it into variable `num_images' then you can do:

```
path  = 'img_'+ str(index + 1).zfill( len( str( num_images) ) )
path += '.png'
```

Which will add the necessary amount of leading zeros. E.g. you have `236` images to convert (that is in our case `num_images = 236`). Another neat trick is `len( str( num_images ) )`. First it creates a string from `236` --> `'236'` and then it finds the length of `len( '236' ) = 3`

This is how the final files will look like `zfill`:

```
img_001.png
img_002.png
.
.
.
img_010.png
img_011.png
.
.
img_100.png
.
.
.
img_236.png
```