# how can I convert an integer matrix to a matrix whose corresponding elements are the bin(elements in the integer matrix) in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I know bin(Z) in python returns a binary equivalent for the integer Z but what I couldn't figure out is how to apply bin to every element of an integer matrix in python.

```
input(2x3)
matrix[[1, 1, 2],[3, 5, 8]]

output(2x3) with 8 bits
matrix[[00000001, 00000001, 00000010],[00000011, 00000101, 00001000]]
```

Comment: You'll have to show an example of this integer matrix …

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy's `binary_repr()` you can convert a given integer to its binary representation as the name indicates. The `width` parameter enables for outputs of given length (8 in this case). However, applying this to matrices or arrays will yield the issue of missing leading zeros. This can be tackled by either using strings in the binary representation or the use of `zfill()` as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733454/best-way-to-format-integer-as-string-with-leading-zeros).
So giving examples of possible solutions:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randint(0,100,(2,3), dtype=int)
print(data)
n,m = data.shape
data_bin = np.zeros((n, m), dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        data_bin[i, j] = np.binary_repr(data[i, j], width=8)
print(data_bin)

data_bin_str = np.zeros((n, m), dtype='|S8')
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        data_bin_str[i, j] = str(np.binary_repr(data[i, j], width=8))
print(data_bin_str)
```

Note the loop-setup as `binary_repr()` has no array support as far as i know (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1868)).

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to use list comprehensions to do it.

[[bin(x) for x in y] for y in matrix]

Comment: It doesn't. Error msg : only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index

Comment: That was for a 2D list, I see now that you're using numpy.matrix. `numpy.matrix([[bin(x) for x in y] for y in matrix.tolist()]) `

Answer (score 0):

for a given input matrix: input_matrix

```
matrix([[bin(int(entry))[2:].zfill(8) for entry in row_vector]for row_vector 
in array(input_matrix)])

examples.

input_matrix = matrix([[1, 1, 2],[3, 5, 8]])

output = matrix([['00000001', '00000001', '00000010'],
                 ['00000011', '00000101', '00001000']], dtype='|S8')
```