# Add 0 to hostname

Tags: python

My file contains IP addresses that I'd like to convert to host names. The IP addresses are the same except for the last three octets.  For example:

```
192.168.38.8
192.168.38.9
192.168.38.10
```

I have the following code in my python script to substitute the IP address with the host name which ends in the final octet.

```
 hostname = re.sub('192.168.38.','Host-Name',lm.group(4))
```

This give me the results:

```
Host-Name8
Host-Name9
Host-Name10
```

How do I get the single digit octets to have a leading zero?  The desired output would be;

```
Host-Name08
Host-Name09
Host-Name10
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to format integer as string with leading zeros?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733454/best-way-to-format-integer-as-string-with-leading-zeros)

Comment: ideally, it should consider **3** digits, according to octet size. `Host-Name008` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display number with leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`re.sub` isn't used correctly.

From [documentation for `re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub), you can pass a string or replacement function that returns a string when a match is found.

> **Notice:**
>   You can use any of the methods in answers to questions in the
>   duplicate flags to pad single digits.

```
def replace_ip(match):
    last_octet = match.group(1)

    return "".join((
        'Host-Name',
        last_octet.zfill(2)
    ))


re.sub(r'192.168.38.(\d+)', replace_ip, ips_from_file)
```

Comment: @ Oluwafemi Sule - Worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You might find just using `split()` easier as follows:

```
for ip_addr in ["192.168.38.8", "192.168.38.9", "192.168.38.10"]:
    print "Host-Name{:02}".format(int(ip_addr.split('.')[3]))
```

This would give you:

```
Host-Name08
Host-Name09
Host-Name10
```