# Another simplified method for the function in python

Tags: python, arrays, string

I have to implement a function in python which returns a string of 4 characters from integers of 0 to 9999.
The value of the string should begin with 0.

Example :

input:

```
3
22
123
1235
```

output:

```
0003
0022
0123
0123
```

The code that I have implemented is:

```
def stringtoZ(n):
    a = str(n)
    if(n < 10):
        string = "0" + "00" + a
    elif (n < 100):
        string = "0" + "0" + a
    elif (n < 1000):
        string = "0" + a
    else:
        string = "0" + a[:3]
    return string;
```

Normally the result is correct, but as I am a beginner in python, I wanted to know if there is another way which can be easier to implement this? 
Thank you so much!

Comment: Use str(n).zfill(4). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733454/best-way-to-format-integer-as-string-with-leading-zeros

Comment: @jarmod `zfill()` wouldn't work when the number has to start with 0 (and truncated if needed)

Comment: @Mohd I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give me an example of an integer between 0 and 9999 that would be problematic?

Comment: @jarmod OP's 4th example: `1235` -> `0123`

Comment: @Mohd OK thanks, I didn't read that final example. What a strange requirement. OK, something like: `str(n).zfill(4) if n < 1000 else str(n//10).zfill(4)`

Comment: @jarmod Yes, I'm not sure how `zfill()` is implemented but I think it would be faster than concatenating/slicing. I'll add it to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use `4-len(a)` if the number is less than 1000 to determine the number of leading zeroes and otherwise `'0' + a[:3]` to slice the first three numbers of the string. For example:

```
def stringtoZ(n):
    a = str(n)
    return '0' * (4-len(a)) + a if n < 1000 else '0' + a[:3]

print(stringtoZ(3), stringtoZ(123), stringtoZ(1234))
# 0003 0123 0123
```

Another approach is what jarmod mentioned in the comment:

```
def stringtoZ(n):
    return str(n).zfill(4) if n < 1000 else str(n//10).zfill(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for valid input, try

```
def z(n):
    if -1 < n < 1000  : return ('000'+str(n))[-4:]
    if -1 < n < 10000 : return '0'+str(n//10)
    raise ValueError('n = %d is out of range (0 ≤ n < 10000).'%n)
```

The first `if` catches all the `n < 1000` numbers and returns the tail
of a a longer string.

The second if catches all the numbers in `999 < n < 10000` and uses
integer division (the `//` operator) to remove the last digit.

The `raise` statement is reached only if `n` is outside the valid
interval, so we can raise an exception (`ValueError` seems
appropriate), providing also an error message for the caller.

Having previously defined `z(n)` in the interpreter we have

```
In [32]: z(4567)
Out[32]: '0456'

In [33]: z(567)
Out[33]: '0567'

In [34]: z(20000)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-34-3a36d9b24c14> in <module>
----> 1 z(20000)

<ipython-input-26-d5602c2c4b24> in z(n)
      2     if -1 < n < 1000  : return ('000'+str(n))[-4:]
      3     if -1 < n < 10000 : return '0'+str(n//10)
----> 4     raise ValueError('n = %d is out of range (0 ≤ n < 10000).'%n)

ValueError: n = 20000 is out of range (0 ≤ n < 10000).
```

And eventually an example of how one can manage the exception in their code:

```
In [35]: for n in (-1, 0, 1, 999, 9999, 10000):
    ...:     try:
    ...:         print('%8d ——→'%n, z(n))
    ...:     except ValueError as e:
    ...:         print(e)
n = -1 is out of range (0 ≤ n < 10000).
       0 ——→ 0000
       1 ——→ 0001
     999 ——→ 0999
    9999 ——→ 0999
n = 10000 is out of range (0 ≤ n < 10000).

In [36]:
```